# make entities with multiple databases

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have to do large refactoring/enhancements on web apps. We decided to use Symfony4.

I want to define 2 (or more) databases: the old one and the new one.
(In the future, I think to have more `location`, `person` databases common at several web apps)

In my researches, I use [Multiple Entity Managers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html), create my databases as mentionned, then create my `src/Entity/Main` and `src/Entity/Customer` folders.

Then, I want to **create my entities**, especially new one with `php bin/console make:entity` but it creates files in `Entity` folder, not in `Entity/Main` (default) or `Customer` and returns

> [ERROR] Only annotation mapping is supported by make:entity

Are there any solution to use this `make:entity` command or should I define all entity files myself?

Nota: I don't put my `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`, it is the same as in help sample except *server_version: '5.6'* to be compliant with my MariaDB version

Comment: After discussion with a college, I am agree that the right approach is to have only one database.  
For my refactoring, new project has its new database and migration scripts are just connecting to old database when migrating.  
To common databases as `location`, `person`, it will separate project with API to connect to (REST API for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to create *Product* entity in *Main* is:

```
php bin/console make:entity Main\\Product
```

and to create *Customer* entity in *Customer* is:

```
php bin/console make:entity Customer\\Customer
```