# Symfony4 multiple databases with same structure

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

For a project I want to keep data separated in multiple databases. I want to create a web-platform where there are 'companies' with 'users'

But I want to create for every company a database and switch to this database when a user goes to the company page like:
`http://localhost/company/{company_name}`

After that they need to login on a page like:
`http://localhost/company/{company_name}/login`
with the user credentials in that database.

Is there a way to generate these databases with a push on the button 
and switch between them when a user visits another path?

Already thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you read https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html and my solved issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850235/make-entities-with-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is possible, but not easy.

The standard behavior is to configure the databases /entity managers/ in the config. Their parameters /name, user, password, endpoint/ are set in the environment variables. In order to have multiple databases you need to set these parameters, but eventually a restart of Apache /if you use it/ may be required.

You can check [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/symfony2/ss3BQhA81dE) for ideas.